# PowerQuery M : Filter Table A by Table B

Tags: powerquery

Table A has a column of payment references (A-INV*, B-CrMemo*, C-INV*, D-PCM* etc.) and Table B has a column of filters to apply (B-Cr*, C-INV*).

I'm trying to get "Table A[Payment References]" to limited to "Table B[Filter]" but nothing I do returns the value I want. (As "Table B[Filter]" has a variety of lengths, I've added a custom column counting the length of the string of each Filter and called the field, LEN.)

My latest attempt is `List.ContainsAny(Text.ToList(Text.Start([Payment References],List.Max("Table B[LEN]"))),"Table B[Filters]"))` which is from guidance I've found [here](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Query/List-Contains-and-List-Startswith/td-p/2120750) but this returns zero results, which I know isn't correct.

Reviewing the guidance on `Text.ToList`, it appears this won't do what I'm looking for, anyway, as it would create a list of each character individually.

Is there a better way to do this filter? I'd rather not do a table-join if I can help it; that seems messy.

Thanks

Comment: Are the `*` literal or wildcard? Should `B-Cr*` filter match `B-CrMemo*` reference?

Comment: Please paste sample data as copiable text along with expected results.

Comment: My apologies. They are wildcards. As such, I've been playing with ".Start" or ".StartWith"

Comment: Is the wild card only numbers?  Can you give a few specific examples of payment references and filters without the wildcards?

Comment: Are you able to sort by payment references at the source instead of in Power Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try creating a list of Text.Start, split new column into rows, and then an inner merge.  That should remove all the extra rows that are created and filter it down to what is in Table B.

The List.Accumulate below is really just

```
{Text.Start([Payment References],5),Text.Start([Payment References],4)}
```

since I only had filters of length 5 and 4.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WctT19AszVIrViVZy0nUu8k3NzTcC85xBEolgpotugLOvoQFCOAmu3tDIWCk2FgA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Payment References" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Payment References", type text}}),
    table_b_lengths = List.Buffer(List.Sort(List.Distinct(TableB[LEN]), Order.Descending)),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Start", each List.Accumulate(table_b_lengths,{},(s,c) => s & {Text.Start([Payment References],c)})),
    #"Expanded Start" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Start"),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Start", {"Start"}, TableB, {"Filter"}, "TableB", JoinKind.Inner)
in
    #"Merged Queries"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this solution; it's working really well. One question comes to mind: is the ```Order.Descending``` required? I'm not used to ```List.Buffer``` or ```List.Accumulate``` functions, so I don't know the impact. Thanks

Comment: Order.Descending is only optional and is helpful if you MIGHT have duplicates (e.g. A-CRM and A-CR filters since A-CR is contained in A-CRM and we are taking first 4 and first 5).  In that case you might choose to keep the longest filter vs the shortest filter and remove duplicates based on descending order.  List.Buffer will help speed up your query if the list is used over and over like it is in a Table.AddColumn.

List.Accumulate is a list generator.

Answer (score 1):

This will filter rows in TableA where column Payment References starts with text from TableB.Column1

Code for TableA:

```
#"NameOfPriorStep" = .....,
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"NameOfPriorStep", "check", (x)=> List.AnyTrue(List.Transform(TableB[Column1], each Text.Contains(x[Payment References],_)))), 
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([check] = true)),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"check"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

In my opinion, you are likely better off doing a merge with fuzzy match, then a Table.RowCount(), as above code will run long for large data sets

```
#"NameOfPriorStep" = .....,
#"Merged Queries" = Table.FuzzyNestedJoin(#"NameOfPriorStep", {"Payment References"}, TableB, {"Column1"}, "TableB", JoinKind.LeftOuter, [IgnoreCase=true, IgnoreSpace=true]),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Custom", each Table.RowCount([TableB])),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Custom] = 1)),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"TableB", "Custom"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach. Yes, it works, but you're right: it's not very quick. I doesn't help that I've got to replicate this on multiple (about 12) tables, and they're all huge. I'm trying to merge the Filter table to the individual tables instead, but this is also taken ages to merge. I was hoping to filter down each table up front, before I start merging the tables into the final result.

Comment: I added the code for fuzzy table match that I assume would be much faster

Comment: Thanks again for your time on this. Unfortunately, I've not been able to replicate the Table.RowCount route; no entry equals 1. I've also timed the Check against my live data and this takes about 4 minutes. Answer 2, provided by @spinfuzer takes a matter of seconds, so I'm going to go ahead with this solution. I really appreciate the time you've put to this, though.

Comment: Glad you got your solution!